# Creating singleton class from a remote service android

Tags: android, singleton, android-service

I have created a remote service. In this remote service i am creating a singleton object. Once created this object should stay till its garbage collected. Now when i access this object from inside the singleton class i getting correct object. but when i am accessing it from outside class it singleton object is null and my class is getting created again. I am loosing all the initialised object.

my singleton class is as follows

```
class myFactory {

    private static myFactory instance;

    private myFactory(){
    }

    public static myFactory getInstance(){
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new myFactory();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

I tried to overide finalize in singleton class to check if the object gets garbage collected but it doesnt come in that function.

Outside the connection factory object where ever i access this singleton object i am getting null and therefore new object is created > what am i doing wrong?

Comment: who told you that you are getting a null ? you cannot get null. You mean you get a new instance?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Singleton, and I don't see why it shouldn't work. But I guess you are trying to use the Singleton in some kind of IPC-context, that would be the problem (since a remote service is afaik always a new Thread).

Question is: Why do you need a Singleton...isn't there a nicer solution? I don't know your whole Service structure, but maybe it makes sense to get the instance of the Factory while binding to the service.

It could help, if you can give more information

Comment: Thanks Philipp for you quick response, I need Singleton bcos i will be creating some objects which I should be able to access in any of my classes. This is kind of factory pattern object. I wanted new object to be created only when this objects gets destroyed.... The factory object is not used by activities it is used by some of the worker classes.

Comment: the structure is like activity starts the service and service creates factory object. the member of factory object are used by below layers of the application like network layer etc.

Comment: Does the service run in the same thread? If not, there is the problem that every thread has an own classloader, thats why singletons won't work.
Maybe you should also consider to get the factory from the service, which is generally the safest approach (since you will probably run everything in different threads to avoid ANR) - [Some hints for Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html)

Comment: The service is running in different process. Phillipp Probably what you are saying is in right direction... I was accessing the the singleton created by service in a broadcast receiver which is defined in the manifest. What I will try is to get broadcastreciever in the same process as the service. For running in service in different process i have given android:process=":remote". If i give same thing to broadcast receiver will it be in the same process as the service

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create a BroadcastReceiver which will be in the same thread/process as the server. But what then? Keep in mind, that the BroadcastReceiver then will run in another thread than the function that starts the BroadcastReceiver and you can't exchange complex Objects between processes without marshalling/unmarshalling them.

Maybe haven't understood it right (I never worked with BroadcastReceiver), but if I understood correctly, you should look into AIDL (which is a pain if you are not used to it, but rewarding if you know how to use it)